# Trying to write a stored procedure with a Identity column to create my table values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a stored procedure that creates a new row of data in my table that has an `Identity` column. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong to get it to store my data in the table.

Here is my table

```
CREATE TABLE [Promotional].[Proposals]
(
    [Proposal_Uid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Prime_Contract] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [Sub_Contract] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [Po_Id] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [Proposal_Title] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Client_Name] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    [Client_Code] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Total_Proposal_Amount] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [ODC_Amount] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [Manager_Name] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [Admin] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [Due_Date] [date] NULL,
    [Start_Date] [date] NULL,
    [End_Date] [date] NULL,
    [Proposal_Number] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Contract_Type] [nvarchar](16) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [Proposal_Uid] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Proposal_Uid] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Here is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Promotional].[Proposals_Create] 
    (@Prime_Contract nvarchar(30),
     @Sub_Contract nvarchar(30),
     @Po_Id nvarchar(30),
     @Proposal_Title nvarchar(50),
     @Client_Name nvarchar(40),
     @Client_Code nvarchar(20),
     @Total_Proposal_Amount decimal(18,2),
     @ODC_Amount decimal(18,2),
     @Manager_Name nvarchar(30),
     @Admin nvarchar(30),
     @Due_Date date,
     @Start_Date date,
     @End_Date date,
     @Proposal_Number nvarchar(20),
     @Contract_Type nvarchar(16),
     @NewId int output)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @NewId IS NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Promotional.Proposals (Prime_Contract, Sub_Contract, Po_Id, Proposal_Title, Client_Name, Client_Code,
                                           Total_Proposal_Amount, ODC_Amount, Manager_Name, Admin, Due_Date, Start_Date, End_Date, Proposal_Number, Contract_Type)
        VALUES (@Prime_Contract, @Sub_Contract, @Po_Id, @Proposal_Number, @Client_Name, @Client_Code,
                @Total_Proposal_Amount, @ODC_Amount, @Manager_Name, @Admin, @Due_Date, @Start_Date, @End_Date,
                @Proposal_Number, @Contract_Type)

        SET @NewId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END

    RETURN @NewId
END
GO
```

I know it's something small I missed. But, my **OUTCOME** is that when you run the procedure, it inserts the values in the correct columns, and the primary key is auto updated without having to stick your own value into the statement. My execution of the statement would be as follows

```
EXEC Promotional.Proposals_Create 'hj','fd','fd','fd','fd','fd','0.23','1.24','fd','fd','2020/08/30','2020/08/30','2020/08/30','fd','fd';
```

And I get this error:

> Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure Promotional.Proposals_Create, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Procedure or function 'Proposals_Create' expects parameter '@NewId', which was not supplied.

I shouldn't have to provide that parameter because it should auto update with my PK which is `Proposal_Uid`. Or do I have to make my `Proposal_Uid` the value returned from `ScopeIdentity`?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: hello @GordonLinoff yes, I am trying to make a stored procedure that Creates a new row of data in my table that has an Identity column. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong to get it to store my data in the table. It accepts the stored procure, but doesn't let me insert values. Gives an error.

Comment: Then please copy-paste said error into your question...

Comment: @Sander Updated.

Comment: So... Your error tells you that you are one input parameter short. If you were to use named input parameters like `EXEC Promotional.Proposals_Create @Prime_Contract='hj', @Sub_Contract='fd', ...` this would be very clear.

Comment: @Sander Yes, but I was told if I create the stored procedure correctly, I wouldn't haft to supply a parameter for ```NewID``` as that auto increments already. Or am I thinking that Scope Identity is not doing what I think it's doing?

Comment: @Airizzo Even if you declare `@NewId` as an output parameter in your stored procedure, you still have to provide the database engine with a variable to store it into. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@NewID` should not be a parameter of the procedure since it is an `IDENTITY` column.

Comment: Your post got me to my answer. I took out the @newId anywhere it was mentioned and  just left Insert INTO code and Values code. That was it, and it worked. Thank you. Auto Increments and everything.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** get the stored procedure to return the generated id by providing an output variable to store its content. This behaviour is also documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure#examples-of-output-parameter).

```
declare @test int;

EXEC Proposals_Create 'hj','fd','fd','fd','fd','fd','0.23','1.24','fd','fd',
                      '2020/08/30','2020/08/30','2020/08/30','fd','fd', @test OUTPUT;

select @test as 'new_identity';

set @test = null; -- because of the IF statement in your procedure...

EXEC Proposals_Create 'hj','fd','fd','fd','fd','fd','0.23','1.24','fd','fd',
                      '2020/08/30','2020/08/30','2020/08/30','fd','fd', @test OUTPUT;

select @test as 'new_identity';
```

The selects return `1` and `2` respectively.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0e0a8d0f5372b64cd0b2f3a2b512c2a5) (Remark: schema name removed in code above and in fiddle).

Comment: yes, I saw. I had a incorrect explanation about Scope Identity and what it did when put into a procedure. I was under the impression that ```ScopeIdentity```, is directly connected to my PK that is also my Identity, and needed to be in the procedure to auto increment and be checked against. I was given bad information and didn't fact check like I should of. I just took out everything associated with it, and left the insert into and values. It worked like a charm with my exec stored procedure line. My mistake for posting a invalid thought about ScopeIdentity.